# What is google's GCLID parameter?

Tags: parameters, google-analytics, google-ads-api

I have read somewhere that a site's url will have GCLID or added with GCLID ,I am not sure about which is the correct sentence.Can anyone please give some brief description about it.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**gclid** represent unique ID for clicks coming from Google's Ad networks (like AdWords). It allows Google to create a unique link between specific ad impression and click. Hope this helps.